# Create a polygon from X and Y columns in df in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geometry, shapely

I am trying to plot the distance between a random point and a polygon in space. I have the coordinates for said polygon in an excel xlsx file like so:

```
X      Y

988    602
1079   598
968    700
1075   699
```

where 988 & 602 are the coordinates(X,Y) of the left top corner, 1079 & 598 of the next one, and so on.

I am using shapely to define a Point for my random point and Polygon to define the Polygon, however, I am struggling to fill it with the data from the two columns. Any suggestions are appreciated! :)

Thanks

Comment: Please include the code using `shapely` that you are having trouble getting to work. Otherwise, it's difficult to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shapely's [`Polygon`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#Polygon) constructor can receive a sequence of coordinate tuples `(x, y)`, which you can create by joining the x and y column of your dataframe using the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

```
x = df['X'].tolist()
y = df['Y'].tolist()

p = Polygon(list(zip(x, y)))
```